# Apache Karaf - Authentication and Authorization via Keycloak

Tags: keycloak, apache-karaf

I use Apache Karaf 4.x for my rest services. I would like to provide authentication and authorization for my services via Keycloak. I do not want to make direct changes in each service. Instead, I would like to configure karaf in the way that if request is not authenticated then it will forward to keycloak to get a session. or maybe there could be client credentials or bearer token and karaf could check that token before allowing to use the service.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/spaces/paxweb/pages/354025473/HTTP+Context+processing to see how Karaf + PaxWeb solves this problem. This mechanism works by default in Red Hat Fuse 7 which is a custom Apache Karaf distribution built to support Camel.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have read the provided wikipage. I understood that pax-web allows to configure security in the level of Apache Karaf and no need to configure sth in the bundle itself. But is there any running example how to configure a service security within pax.web configuration?

Comment: https://github.com/jboss-fuse/karaf-quickstarts/blob/7.x.redhat-7-x/security/keycloak/fuse-keycloak.adoc